# Escaping special characters in JSP with JSTL from user input retrieved through AJAX as XML

Tags: java, ajax, xml, jsp, servlets

So i've developed a commenting system where users can enter comments. If the comment thread is too long, then there is a "View previous comments" link users can click on to fetch more comments. The fetched comments are retrieved via AJAX and returned as XML:

**AJAX REQUEST IN FEED.JSP:**

```
...
$.get("../GetPostComments", $.param(params), function(responseXml) {
$("#example").prepend($(responseXml).find("cfeed").html()); 
});
```

**GetPostComments SERVLET:**

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
...
  Post post = c.getCommentsWithOffset(type, postid, offset);
  request.setAttribute("post", post);
  request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/xml/comments.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

**comments.jsp**

```
...
<c:out escapeXml="true" value="${example.comment}"></c:out>
...
```

**Everything works great!** The user can fetch new comments if the thread is too long. **But** if one of the fetched comments contains a special xml character, then it breaks and will not display anything. Despite the fact that i am already escaping with:

```
<c:out escapeXml="true" value="${example.comment}"></c:out>
```

Anyone have any idea why this could be happening? For some reason fetching XML content via ajax within another .jsp file seems to cancel out the escaping i am already doing??

[image]

**EDIT console log:**

(probably not much use...) It just shows where it broke. `(<ul></ul>)` Each comment exits within an `li`.

[image]

Comment: can you add a console.log (responseXml) in the ajax callback ?

Comment: edited @BigMike

Comment: maybe it's me, but can't see the "comment" elements in that console log, just the opening of the UL and the closing.

Comment: comment elements? Yeah they are not showing because of the xml character that is breaking it.. So we only get the ul element, but not the li element where the comment is

Comment: I was expecting to see the full doc as server by the AS, with the broken XML char too. Comments or not it should contain ALL what's served.

Comment: hmm, well any ideas why it's not showing all the content ?

Comment: I think you have some other issue in the emitting JSP, check the c:foreach, I know it's nasty but you can just <!-- about to iterate on ${collection.size} --> before the iteration tag, that should be visible in the console.log and may give you some better hint where to look at.

Comment: Perhaps, ill give it a try. But i'm not sure how it could be another issue if the code works perfectly fine until i add special xml characters...

Comment: @BigMike i found the issue, it was something completely unrelated like you assumed lol. The collection.size comment you made is what helped me solve the issue, was doing something silly in the backend. If you post any answer ill give you the points, otherwise going to delete this. Thanks for helping me debug.

Comment: some nice (albeit subtle) hints and you found the problem, you deserve those points more, so post the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to BigMike in the comment section above, wouldn't have solved the problem if it wasn't for his hints. It had to do with something quite unrelated which coincidentally made it look as if it was an xml escaping issue. (because it was fetching comments for a different post)

> /facepalm

[image]